# Utilizar un Storyboard para varios controles

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, xaml

Buenas tardes, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo utilizar un storyboard en otros controles ya que cuando lo creo queda asociado a un control especifico en el Storyboard.TargetName, en mi aplicacion wpf queda ligado a una imagen (imagen1) y al intentar utilizarlo en otra imagen(imagen2)siempre retorna a la referencia inicial. este es el codigo del storyboard y vb

```
<Storyboard x:Key="efectoAumento">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgIcono">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="easingDoubleKeyFrame" KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.514"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgIcono">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.514"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="efectoNormal">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgIcono">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.514"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imgIcono">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.514"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>`  Private Sub EfectoHover(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim efecto As Storyboard = Resources("efectoAumento")
    efecto.Begin(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub EfectoNormal(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim efecto As Storyboard = Resources("efectoNormal")
    efecto.Begin(Me)
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que estás intentando hacer es un efecto Hover. La forma de poder reutilizar las animaciones, no es cambiando el TargetName de las mismas, es creando un style con la funcionalidad que puedan compartir todos los objetos que desees.

Para eso tienes que crearte las animaciones, sin las etiquetas de TargetName, y crearte un style, para el objeto en cuestión, en el ejemplo un Image. Dentro de este style, añadiremos un property trigger, para la propiedad IsMouseOver, y una animación de entrada y otra de salida. Después le indicamos a las Image que queremos nuestro style y danzando.

Te dejo el código de ejemplo, he utilizado unas animaciones básicamente igual a las tuyas, y se lo he aplicado a 2 Images:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="EfectoAumento1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="257"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="300"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="220"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="300"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="EfectoNormal1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="300"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="257"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="300"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="220"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style x:Key="ImgMouseOverStyle" TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource EfectoAumento1}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource EfectoNormal1}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image" Style="{StaticResource ImgMouseOverStyle}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="274,183,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Source="Images/unnamed.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="image1" Style="{StaticResource ImgMouseOverStyle}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="225" Margin="667,150,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Source="Images/810CGXknuRL._SL1500_.jpg"/>

</Grid>
```